# what does fgets() store in the array

Tags: arrays, c, string, char, fgets

So I looked for fgets() in Kernighan and Ritchie book. So it goes like this:

`char *fgets(char *s, int n, FILE *stream)`

fgets reads at most the next n-1 characters into the array s, stopping if a newline is encountered; the newline is included in the array, which is terminated by '\0'. fgets returns s, or NULL if end of file or error occurs.

So my confusion is, if a file contains the following lines

```
Earth is the third planet from the Sun
The only astronomical object known to harbor life 
About 29% of Earth's surface is land consisting of continents and islands
```

If by using fgets() I read the file, so what will 's' contain?
would it contain `"Earth is the third planet from the Sun\n\0"` or it would contain `"Earth is the third planet from the Sun\0\n"` or something else?

Comment: What part of K&R's description is confusing you?

Comment: It will depend on the buffer length passed to `fgets()`.

Comment: @MikeCAT: Just assume the buffer is sufficiently large to contain the entire line.

Comment: @RobertHarvey How about the buffer length passed, not the buffer itself? I see some people do like `char s[1024]; fgets(s, 100, stdin);`

Comment: @MikeCAT: Buffer length is not mentioned anywhere in the question, and your statement is inaccurate.  The amount read may also depend on whether or not there is a newline in the input.

Comment: [Let's write some code to see what is stored in the array.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qt7Zc4etDMueKKUe)

Comment: Suppose fgets store this: `"Earth is the third planet from the Sun\0\n"`. Does it matter what is stored _after_ the `'\0'`? Keep in mind that strings are terminated by a `'\0'`.

Comment: OK, I think I see where your confusion lies.  The newline is stored first, then the terminating character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, `char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)` reads a line from the specified stream (stdin, file..), function reads line and stops when the *end-of-file is reached* or when *(n-1) characters are read*.

So, in your example `s` will contain `Earth is the third planet from the Sun\n\0`

Another case when the number of characters in line is more than (n-1). Let n = 10, then `s` will contain `Earth is \0`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a description of `fgets` from the C standard itself-

> § 7.21.7.2
>
> The fgets function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by n from the
> stream pointed to by stream into the array pointed to by s. No additional characters are read after a
> new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file. A null character is written immediately
> after the last character read into the array.

There are 2 primary things to notice here to answer your question.

- > The fgets function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by n from the stream pointed to by stream into the array pointed to by s

  So the `n` you pass matters, it signifies the maximum number of characters to read, **including the null terminator**.

  So, if you pass `100` as `n`, it'll read **at most** 99 characters from the file and put a `'\0'` at the end of that.

  What does "at most" mean? Well, `fgets` will stop as soon as it encounters a new line (or if the file just ends, obviously).

  > No additional characters are read after a new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file

  This means `fgets` will read either **upto and including** the first newline character `\n`, or upto `n - 1` characters, from the file - whichever happens first
- > A null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array.

  Which means, after *all the character reading from the file* has finished, according to the terms mentioned previously, a `\0` is written to the buffer.

So to answer your question, on your example file, if you did `fgets(s, 1024, file)` - assuming `s` is a pointer to a character array/buffer that can hold **at least** 1024 characters and `file` is a `FILE*` to your file - you'd get the result

`Earth is the third planet from the Sun\n\0`

Since `fgets` stopped at the first `\n`, as that happened before passing the char limit as indicated by `n`. Then it put the `\0` at the end of the buffer.

Note that `fgets` not only writes to the buffer you passed to it, *but also returns that same buffer* - do not be confused by this. They are pointers to the same location.

Answer (score 2):

OK, let's write some code to see what is stored in the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char s[64];
    int size = sizeof(s);
    int i;
    /* initialize array */
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) s[i] = (char)0xff;

    /* call fgets() */
    fgets(s, size, stdin);

    /* print contents of the array */
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%02X ", (unsigned char)s[i]);
        if ((i + 1) % 16 == 0) {
            int j, offset = (i / 16) * 16;
            for (j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
                putchar(0x20 <= s[offset + j] && s[offset + j] < 0x7f ? s[offset + j] : '.');
            }
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input (as specified in the question):

```
Earth is the third planet from the Sun
The only astronomical object known to harbor life 
About 29% of Earth's surface is land consisting of continents and islands
```

[Output](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JtXoY4g4bknwod94):

```
45 61 72 74 68 20 69 73 20 74 68 65 20 74 68 69 Earth is the thi
72 64 20 70 6C 61 6E 65 74 20 66 72 6F 6D 20 74 rd planet from t
68 65 20 53 75 6E 0A 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF he Sun..........
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF ................
```

It contains `"Earth is the third planet from the Sun\n\0"`.

Let's check also the case when the buffer length specified in less then the required size to store that.

Replacing `fgets(s, size, stdin);` with `fgets(s, 32, stdin);`, I got [output](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Yye1dVcw8Wi0OK8o):

```
45 61 72 74 68 20 69 73 20 74 68 65 20 74 68 69 Earth is the thi
72 64 20 70 6C 61 6E 65 74 20 66 72 6F 6D 20 00 rd planet from .
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF ................
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF ................
```

This suggests that it will store `n-1` characters and 1 terminating null-character in this case.